# Find $1,2,3,4$th degree Taylor polynomial of $e^{x^2}$ at $x=0$

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

I wrote Taylor polynomial of $e^{x^2}$ until the term contains $x^4$ (it is forth degree polynomial):

$$P_4(x)=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}$$

And obviously second degree polynomial is  $$P_2(x)=1+x^2$$

But I doubt about first and third degree polynomial because we don't have $x$ and $x^3$.

So can we say $P_1(x)=1$ and $P_3(x)=1+x^2$ ?

Comment: There is no third degree polynomial, since $\exp(x^2)=1+x^2+ax^3+O(x^4)$ implies $a=0$, hence the polynomial is $1+x^2$, which has degree $2$. The Taylor polynomial *"of degree at most 3"* is simply $1+x^2$. Likewise for degree $1$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thanks for the answer. so in this problem we have only polynomials of degree $2$ and degree $4$. am I right?

Comment: It depends on how $P_1$ and $P_3$ are defined.  If they're the usual Taylor polynomials, then the answer is "yes", although they don't turn out to actually be of degrees one and three.